# Regex for date pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

Trying to write a regex expression in C# that accepts any/all of the following:

1. 02/01/1968
2. 2/01/1968
3. 2/1/1968

(This question is somewhat different then other similar questions in that this is to be a single word, in mm/dd/yyyy format. Only the pattern is needed without verification as to its possibility. i.e., 99/99/9999 is o.k.)

I am getting nowhere fast. Here is as far as I've gotten (which only recognizes 02/01/1968):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$",RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
Match x = regex.Match(birthdate);
if (x.Success == false) return;
```

Thanks for any help. (An explanation with the regex would be most appreciated).

Comment: `@"^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$"`

Comment: You'll be better off using `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

Comment: Please don't compare booleans to `true` and `false`. Change `if (x.Success == false) return;` to `if (!x.Success) return;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you **must** use regex to validate the format, define the `{min,max}` in the range quantifier:

```
^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}$
```

Comment: `\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}` allows you to have 2 or 4 digit year. The ^ and $ the are limiting you to only having the date in there line

Comment: Note this will match invalid dates like "99/99/0000"

Comment: @owen79 That'll also allow you to have 3 digit years or match 4 digits of a year when there's a fifth digit after. You'd want `/\b\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/(?:\d{2}|\d{4})\b/`

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned in comments, use a datetime parser. To get the right regex(returning only valid datetimes) can be very complex and hard to maintain.

```
var formats = new[] { "d/M/yyyy", "dd/M/yyyy", "d/MM/yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy" };
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, formats, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    //parsed correctly
}
```

BTW: It is not clear in your question whether you want `dd/mm` or `mm/dd`, I chose the first one

Comment: Looking for mm/dd/yyyy. Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne then formats would be `var formats = new[] { "M/d/yyyy", "M/dd/yyyy", "MM/d/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy" };`

Comment: This IS better, but I'm trying to learn regex pattern matching. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a regex that checks the right number of days per month, including for February during leap years:

```
var reg = new Regex(@"\b(((0?[469]|11)/(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])|0?2/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]))/([1-9]\d{3}|\d{2})|0?2/29/([1-9]\d)?([02468][048]|[13579][26]))\b", RegexOptions.ECMAScript | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

**Breaking up the regex this way should be easy to understand:**

- Months with 30 days: `0?[469]|11`
- Days maxed at 30: `0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30`
- Months with 31 days: `0?[13578]|1[02]`
- Days maxed at 31: `0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]`
- Days maxed at 28: `0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]`
- Any year from 1000+ (including 2 digit years): `[1-9]\d{3}|\d{2}`
- Feb 29: `0?2/29`
- Last two digits of leap years (divisible by 4): `[02468][048]|[13579][26]`
- `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` is important to specify to ensure `\d` only matches 0-9 digits from English.
- `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` eliminates the need for non-capturing groups of `(?:)`

Comment: I don't know why this was marked down, but it helps in learning the regex--it will take awhile to understand this. :)

Comment: I can understand the downvote since having a huge regular expression is really convoluted and regex isn't the best tool for the task. However the question did specifically ask for regex and this literally takes care of all corner cases (while still taking all the shortcuts I could think of).

Comment: Correction to the above comment - @Pluto here has an absolutely elegant original answer. It takes care of recognizing a date pattern embedded in a string even when one has no knowledge of the date format. All one needs to do is remove both \b word boundaries and replace the separators "/" (slash) with "[/- ]?" (slash, dash, space : one or none) so that it can detect dates without any obvious markers.  Linked here - https://regexr.com/57bgg

Comment: @ParasParmar Adding onto that, you can ensure the separators are the same by using a named group (since we have explicit capture on) and backreferences. For instance `(?<sep>/|-| )` and later on `\1` (I haven't tested this but it should work). Forking off of your regular expression, this is demonstrated here: https://regexr.com/57cnp

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
public static class Date_Regex
{
    static string DateRegex = @"\d?[\/|\-|\s]?\d?[\/|\-|\s]\d(\s?)[\/|\-|\s]?\d?(\s?)[\/|\-|\s]\d{4}[\s]?$"; 
    public static string RegexMatches(string content)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(content, DateRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline)) 
        {
            sb.Append(match.Value + "; ");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

}
```